# React custom Hook, too many rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My custom hooks is this:

```
const useCustom = (data) => {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  if (data.length > 0) {
    let sum1 = 0;
    let sumA2 = 0;
    data.forEach((d) => {
      if (d.objective) {
        sum1 += d.weight;
      } else {
        sum2 += d.weight;
      }
      return null;
    });
    setValue1(sum1);
    setValue2(sum2);
  }
  const array1 = [
    {
      title: 'Title 1',
      value: value1
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 2',
      value: value2
    }
  ];
  const array2 = [
    {
      title: 'Title 3',
      value: value1 + value2
    }
  ];
  return {
    array1,
    array2
  };
};


export default useCustom;
```

Then I'm calling it:

```
const { array1, array2 } = useCustom(data);
```

And doing some stuff in `return` with `array1` and `array2`.

Should I return (in the hook) the `setValues` setters instead the array? I don't get it.

EDIT: I tried this. The hooks now is this one:

```
const useCustom = (data) => {
  const [value1, setValue1] = useState(0);
  const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0);
  let sum1 = 0;
  let sumA2 = 0;
  if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach((d) => {
      if (d.objective) {
        sum1 += d.weight;
      } else {
        sum2 += d.weight;
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  const get1 = async () => setValue1(sum1);
  const get2 = async () => setValue2(sum2);

  const array1 = [
    {
      title: 'Title 1',
      value: value1
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 2',
      value: value2
    }
  ];
  const array2 = [
    {
      title: 'Title 3',
      value: value1 + value2
    }
  ];
  return {
    array1,
    array2,
    get1,
    get2
  };
};
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
   const { get1, get 2, array1, array2 } = useCustom(data);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    (async () => {
      await get1();
      await get2();
    })();
  }
}, [data]);
```

I think is working, but it looks weird all that async func in the useEffect

Comment: You are calling `setValue1` and `setValue2` every render. They should be called outside of the render cycle, either in callbacks or inside a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a "Too many re-renders" error with React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376595/getting-a-too-many-re-renders-error-with-react-hooks)

Comment: @EmileBergeron Not much, I know a that calling a set state inside something rerenders and call again the set state goes to a infinite loop, but I don't get how, In my case, I can return the values with the hook , as you said, as a callback or where in which useEffect

Comment: Edit: I will put my new code with what I did